# Setting minDate with a variable with flatpickr

Tags: javascript, twig, flatpickr

Couldn't find any answers on related threads or on the [flatpickr documentation](https://flatpickr.js.org) so posting here hoping for a miracle.

I'm using flatpickr and have to set a minDate based on a variable.

```
var $date = $('#calendar').data('date');
console.log ($date); // this will return the correct value

$("#calendar").flatpickr( {
    altInput: true,
    altFormat: "F j, Y",
    dateFormat: "Ymd",
    minDate:  $date , 
    maxDate: new Date().fp_incr(60), // 60 days from now
    disableMobile: "true",
    });
```

And on my page I have

```
<input id="calendar" placeholder="Pick a date" data-date="{{ "now"|date("Ymd") }}" >
```

I'm using twig so my console.log will return today's date but it has no impact on the minDate.
In the future the minDate will not be today's date, I just used it to test.

In an [older version of flatpickr](https://unpkg.com/flatpickr@1.7.9/index.html#maxmindate) you could set these types of variables directly in  instead of in the js code, but it seems like it's unfortunately not in use anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to `flatpickr` documentation

> Date Strings, which **must match the dateFormat** chronologically 
>   `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM`

So, `"now"|date("Ymd")` is invalid, try `"now"|date("Y-m-d")`

https://flatpickr.js.org/examples/#supplying-dates-for-flatpickr

Comment: Ymd is the correct date format I need and also stated in the option configuration (dateFormat: "Ymd") e.g. 20191206 and not 2019-12-06

Comment: `dateFormat: "Ymd"` is only applied for values. Use another attribute `data-mindate="{{ "now"|date("Y-m-d") }}"` if you need `data-date` as `Ymd`

Comment: Edit: After removing dateFormat it actually works! I have no idea why it only works on the default date format, though

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with your last sentence, could you clarify/elaborate?

Comment: I thought you need `data-date` as `Ymd` format for some other purpose

Comment: Yes, that was my initial intent although I can probably transform it twig now that I now I can change minDate through a variable. I just am not sure what your suggestion was on how to achieve that. Either way, thanks for the help so far

Answer (score 0):

**DYNAMIC SOLUTION**

We can set a minimum date for flatpickr dynamically

Let's say we have a shipping date field and we do not want it to be earlier than the payment date

```js
flatpickr("#shipping_date", {});
```

```html
<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="shipping_date" class="col-form-label text-right">Shipping Date</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="shipping_date" id="shipping_date" value="" data-toggle="flatpickr">
</div>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
```

We can set a minimum date for shipping date field when document loaded like that

```js
flatpickr("#shipping_date", {});

var payment_date = '2022-08-06';

$(document).ready(function(){
  const element = document.querySelector("input[name=shipping_date]");
  
  element._flatpickr.config.onOpen.push(function(dateObj, dateString, flatpickrInstance) {
    var minimumDate = moment(payment_date).format('YYYY-MM-DD');//e.x. payment_date -> 2022-08-06
    var minimumDateVars = minimumDate.split('-');
    flatpickrInstance.set('minDate', new Date(parseInt(minimumDateVars[0]), parseInt(minimumDateVars[1]) - 1, parseInt(minimumDateVars[2])));
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="shipping_date" class="col-form-label text-right">Shipping Date</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="shipping_date" id="shipping_date" value="" data-toggle="flatpickr">
</div>
```

Full Code

[Code Pen](https://codepen.io/fkeler/pen/bGvMmjP)